# Downloading GIS layers from India-WRIS (Water Resources Information System of India)?

Tags: data, web, download, india

How do you download GIS layers from the [India-WRIS (Water Resources Information System of India)](http://www.india-wris.nrsc.gov.in/) web GIS application?

Comment: Are you sure that you have rights to extract data from the portal? I'll say that the copyright of the data rests with Government of India, ISRO & CWC. It's best that you use the Data download module.

Answer (score 1):

I just visited the [Water Resources Information System of India](http://www.india-wris.nrsc.gov.in/) and noticed that there is a Data Download button under WRIS Connect in its left hand panel.

I recommend that you follow where that leads you.